# Virtual monitor / desktop accessable through vnc only (windows 7)

Tags: display, desktop, vnc

I have the following challenge. I would like a virtual monitor / desktop on my windows 7 pc which is not neccessarily visible to me when i use the pc. Instead i want to access this virtual screen only by using a vnc or rdp connection.

Basically i have written an application that should run on the virtual screen, and which should only be accessible through vnc. I then want to use an ipad to connect to the virtual screen through vnc.

This way i can access some specific apps on my pc through the ipad, but these apps are not visible to an ordinary user, i.e. They are only available to a vnc client (ipad) connecting to the virtual desktop / monitor.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks on advance!

Comment: Realize that unless you are VNCing into an actual VM two people won't be able to use the same PC.

Comment: Im not sure why i would want two people using the same pc? I need one user using a pc, and the same user accessing a seperate virtual monitor on the same pc through vnc from an external device (ipad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways I can think of.

1. Get or enable a second monitor, but don't have one connected.
2. <strike>Get [Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) and run the programs on one of the other desktops.</strike>
3. Install [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or something similar and run a virtualized PC in there.

As I said in my comment, options 1 and 2 prevent two people from using the PC, which may be OK for your situation, but are easier to accomplish.  Option 3, running a Virtual PC has the benefit of being able to use the PC while someone is on the iPad working.

Strike out option 2 as it will show on your monitor as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I dont think that a vm is a possibility, as i need an application running on the same machine, but on a seperate monitor (preferably) only accessible through vnc. Basically the app that should run on the second virtual monitor is an app that interfaces with the applications running on the main physical screen.

Comment: Ah, didn't know it had to interact with apps on the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

I found an ipad version of maxivista, and it somewhat serves my purpose. Instead of a virtual screen, maxivista recognizes the ipad as a physical screen. So i can drag the app i need to the ipad screen. It works ok though it doesnt support input from the ipad unfortunately.

In any case thanks steve for the answer.