# can Windows be hacked to have "huge" screen resolution and not transmit it to monitor, i.e. only for remote desktop viewing?

Tags: windows, vnc, resolution, virtual-desktop

the question is somewhat reminiscent of this one [Virtual monitor / desktop accessable through vnc only (windows 7)](https://superuser.com/questions/164737/virtual-monitor-desktop-accessable-through-vnc-only-windows-7) . I have read that one of the reasons why you should not have Windows try have screen resolution above what the machine will support is that this will fry the graphics chip. (Is it the only reason?) Well, so suppose we wanted to have huge resolution anyway, could we hack Windows into having a "huge" virtual desktop and simply not transmit its data to the (inherently incompatible) graphics hardware?

Does Windows have inherent internal limits on (virtual desktop) screen resolution?

If the graphics related hardware were causing trouble and we could not convince Windows to stop interacting with it, could it be physically disabled on the motherboard?